# osd_clock alternative

Tags: fonts

**Intro:** `osd_clock` is a small utility that continuosly displays date and/or time in an OSD style

**My use case:** I use `osd_clock` when showing full screen materials, so that I can counteract my excessive loquacity and finish my presentations with a reasonable delay...

**My complaint:** `osd_clock` uses ONLY the old bitmapped fonts, that on a 120DPI screen need to be enlarged and become very jagged - also the number of possible choices is limited.

***My question:*** are there any small programs that can play a similar role but using modern vector based fonts — possibly without installing a lot of dependencies but if I have to install a few hundred megabytes to have a nice OSD clock I'd be happy anyway.

---

Ps: I have a vague recollection of a font server that served `.ttf` font and the such in terms of `XLFD` requests... Could such font server be useful to solve my problem?

Comment: Your font server recollection sounds like [`xfstt`](https://www.hadrons.org/software/xfstt/).

Comment: @StephenKitt `xfstt`, exactly/  I'll have a look at it, thank you Stephen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is `aosd_cat`.  Far from perfect, anyway it can render in an OSD style 
an Unicode string using any font known to `fontconfig`.
The program has different issues, the main one is, it's the offspring of an abandoned project (the Atheme project) but it's packaged in a number of important Linux distributions (Debian, Ubuntu, ?) so I hope that it will stay around for a while...

It has to be adapted to my question (a better looking OSD clock) like this:

```
$ while true ; do date +%R ; sleep 60 ; done | aosd_cat -u 59500 &
```

where `-u 59500` is the duration in milliseconds that every line of input has to stay on screen. The program has options for transparencies, fonts, fade-in/out, screen placement, colors so it can be customized to death... With respect to what the clock displays, `man date` has all the answers.

---

ps: I later realized that `aosd_cat` is drawing the string in a transparent, undecorated rectangular window that, unfortunately, intercepts mouse clicks, hence it is impossible to access, e.g., the menus of the underlying application.

I can live with that (my main use case is having a clock on screen during a presentation) but I want to warn you that this is not a *perfect* OSD clock...